# openafs module build problem kernel 3.12.6 under 13.10

Tags: kernel, afs

Just installed ubuntu 13.10 on macbook pro 10,1.

I upgraded the kernel to 3.12.6 in vain hope that the thunderbolt display would work (it didn't) and hot plugging would work (it didn't) (but installing nvidia proprietary drivers 331.20 did help with the display).

I would like to install openafs client however building the kernel module fails.
I run:

```
sudo module-assistant prepare openafs-modules
module-assistant auto-build openafs-modules
```

module building fails, I attatch the relevant snip of the log file:

```
building in directory: MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP'
Makefile.common:50: warning: overriding commands for target `.c.o'
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/config/Makefile.config:141: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.c.o'
env EXTRA_CFLAGS="" /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/make_kbuild_makefile.pl MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP openafs.ko /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/config/Makefile.config Makefile.afs Makefile.common
env EXTRA_CFLAGS="" make -C /usr/src/linux M=/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP modules 2>&1 | tee .makelog
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12.6-031206-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP/afs_error.o
In file included from /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/afs_osi.h:440:0,
             from /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/rx/rx_clock.h:46,
             from /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/rx/rx.h:29,
             from /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/afsincludes.h:30,
             from /usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP/afs_error.c:34:
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h: In function ‘afs_set_cr_uid’:
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h:160:17: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘kuid_t’ from type ‘uid_t’
 cred->fsuid = uid;
             ^
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h: In function ‘afs_set_cr_gid’:
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h:164:17: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘kgid_t’ from type ‘gid_t’
 cred->fsgid = gid;
             ^
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h: In function ‘afs_set_cr_ruid’:
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h:168:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘kuid_t’ from type ‘uid_t’
 cred->uid = uid;
           ^
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h: In function ‘afs_set_cr_rgid’:
/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/afs/LINUX/osi_machdep.h:172:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘kgid_t’ from type ‘gid_t’
 cred->gid = gid;
           ^
make[6]: *** [/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP/afs_error.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [_module_/usr/src/modules/openafs/src/libafs/MODLOAD-3.12.6-031206-generic-SP] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12.6-031206-generic'
rm .makelog
```

When I try to install openafs-modules-dkms the details window in synaptic says:

```
Selecting previously unselected package openafs-modules-dkms.
(Reading database ... 230488 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openafs-modules-dkms (from .../openafs-modules-dkms_1.6.5-1ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
Setting up openafs-modules-dkms (1.6.5-1ubuntu3) ...
Loading new openafs-1.6.5 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.12.6-031206-generic
Building initial module for 3.12.6-031206-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.12.6-031206-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.12.6-031206-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/openafs/1.6.5/build/make.log for more information.
```

In the make.log file the errors are the same as when building through the module-assistant (just the paths to the files indicated are different)

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks a lot!

Wojtek

Answer (score 0):

At the time that you installed openafs, I think the openafs package didn't support building against that kernel; this is [LP #1246675](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openafs/+bug/1246675). According to that bug report, this issue was fixed with a new version of the openafs package, so the solution is to upgrade. Or, more generally, to apply the following three patches, referenced in that bug:

- http://git.openafs.org/?p=openafs.git;a=commitdiff;h=70790f87b7b0ef3746c043a868c4306e05008ecd
- http://git.openafs.org/?p=openafs.git;a=commitdiff;h=30160ad6eec3c290a770b6069fc106f452e5b4ba
- http://git.openafs.org/?p=openafs.git;a=commitdiff;h=8f88530289297117b001d81843e3ac23564815d0